# Check if recaptcha2 is filled before submitting the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, recaptcha

How to check if the new (ver 2) recaptcha is filled in befor submitting 
the form?

Problem is that this captcha is inside iframe and is not allowing to read ids from it.

To clear things out - i don't want to verify the captcha but just check if its filled at all before i submit the form.

**EDIT**:

I have a form inside the bootstrap modal, if i will submit it to check for captcha server side then i would have to redirect user back to page he was using and show the modal again with error notification.


It would be rather bad user expereince, in my view.

Comment: May i ask why the down vote?

Comment: I did not downvote, but Isn't the whole purpose of recaptcha to validate the input? what is the problem if it's not filled? it will just return an error...

Comment: The recaptcha doc page seems to have an example of alerting the recaptcha response on the client. https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display
Basically you need `grecaptcha.getResponse(widgetId1)`

Comment: @Tallmaris Yes, thank you, getResponse() should be used, if you will post answer i will mark it as best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best option would be to use the `getResponse` from the recaptcha API:

```
grecaptcha.getResponse(opt_widget_id)
```

`opt_widget_id` is optional and is the id returned from the `render` call, although, if missing, it will refer to the first created recaptcha widget (if you have only one widget this will suffice).

[Docs are here for reference](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#js_api).

Answer (score 0):

ok, i <strike>should</strike> can use callback to do this:

```
var captchaFilled = false;
var formValidator =  function(data){

  if(data.length>10){
    captchaFilled = true;
}
}
    $('#form1').on('submit', function(e) {


            if(captchaFilled===false){
              e.preventDefault();  
              alert("verify yourself");
              return false;
            }
            else{
              alert("ok");
                return true;
            }


        });

    grecaptcha.render('captchadiv', {
                'sitekey' : '************',
                'callback' : formValidator
    });
```